# what is the difference between original_nameservers and nameservers in zone detail results of cloudflare api

Tags: cloudflare

Can't find what they exactly meant by these.Was trying to match nameservers from dig result and there api result.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCv0G.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

original_nameservers are the value for the nameservers prior to moving the domain to Cloudflare (captured at the time the domain was being onboarded to CF). Nameservers are the values that the domain should be using to be active on Cloudflare in a full setup.